# DeCode Time in Hive - What are the Decoding Rules?

Tags: hadoop, hive, datetime-format

Hive displays time as numbers like  `1480080726000` or `1398284083000` - What are the Decoding Rules?

Answer (score 0):

Those are unix epoch timestamps in milliseconds (those '000' in the ends represents milliseconds). You can try with:

```
from_unixtime ( <time> )
```

You can also call the function with two argument, specifying the time format you desire. For example, if you need only the date you can do:

```
from_unixtime ( <time> , 'yyyy-MM-dd' )
```

For example, removing last three zeros (that don't give you additional information) you can display your two timestamps directly from CLI with:

```
select from_unixtime ( 1480080726 );
select from_unixtime ( 1398284083 );
```

Comment: Thanks - It was very help full

Comment: You're welcome! If this post helped you, could you please mark the answer to close this thread?